# Searchkick score higher the sooner the word appears in field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, elasticsearch, searchkick

Using the Searchkick gem I'm trying to increase the result score in when the word appears in the text so when the search query appears at the start of the field it should get a higher score if when there is a word in front of it, but it should still get a higher score than if the search query appears all the way at the end.

```
@products = Product.search(
        params[:query],
        where: {
          is_active: true,
          is_hidden: false
        },
        fields: [
          {"search_text^20" => :text_start},
          {"search_text^5" => :word},
          {"name^5" => :word},
          {"brand^2" => :word},
          {"description^1" => :word}
        ],
        boost_by: {
          cached_outgoing_click_count: {
            factor: 1
          }
        }
      )
```

This is the closest I have gotten to what I wanted but it's not entirely what I'm looking for